# How to automate opening NeoVim inside WSL of Alacritty Terminal?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, neovim, alacritty

I'm on Windows 11, and trying to automate the following with a .bat script:

1. Create a new instance of Alacritty terminal
2. Enter WSL inside of the Alacritty terminal
3. Open NeoVim after entering WSL

I have gotten as far as steps 1 and 2, but cannot seem to work out step 3. This is what my .bat file looks like right now:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Alacritty\alacritty.exe" -e wsl
exit
```

I have tried adding `-e nvim`, but that just causes this error:

```
<3>WSL (398) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:577: execvpe nvim failed 2
<3>WSL (398) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:586: Create process not expected to return
```

In addition, replacing `-e wsl` with `-e "wsl nvim"` gives me `command not found`, even though I have confirmed that NeoVim is added to my `$PATH` in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have your .bashrc start Neovim when it is sourced upon Linux loading up.

Meaning add `bash nvim` to your .bashrc file on the WSL side to immediately start neovim once your script switching to WSL ends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It has been edited, thanks!